# Extract/Export configuration from oracle 6i forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have an Oracle Forms 6i app right now on windows XP. It is using ms-access odbc. I am really noob to oracle forms.

Now i want to move this app on another pc. How i can export the all configuration of the current oracle forms. If you have any queries about system and app please let me know .

I have installed oracle 6i forms on new machine, and when i am running the app its showing ora03121 error.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps:

1. Install 6i runtime on mentioned PC.
2. Configure TNS file as previous PC.
3. Create MS-Access ODBC as previous PC.

Hope your problem will solved.

Comment: how to configure TNS file ?

Comment: i tried to configure the tns file...copy pasted from old pc too.. but still its not working

Comment: Can you share your TNS?

Comment: TNS files are for connecting with oracle database. If your existing application have any requirement to connect with oracle database you need to configure TNS file. Again if you need only connection ODBC data source then make sure you install Open Client Adapter during/after runtime installation. Then you have to create same named ODBC in new PC. While creating ODBC go to advance tab and give user name and password for mentioned ODBC. This user name and password should be same as previous ODBC.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)  do i have to install oracle open client adapter separately ? from where i can install this ?

Comment: Yes, you have to install Oracle Open Client Adapter separately. You can install this using forms 6i installer in custom mode.

Comment: i installed oracle open client adapter, now it's showing "FRM-40735: ON-LOGON trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-06502"